# how to run a function every 10 seconds automatically in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a gui that needs to have the information in its labels refresh every so often and I have a function that would do so. I was wondering how can i call that function every 10 seconds automatically.

Currently I have a button that refreshes the information but that has to be manually pressed.

```py
bRefreshSystem = tk.Button(text="System Refresh", command=refreshSystem)
```

Currently my solution does work but its not optimal, so how can i call refreshSystem automatically every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

No need for threads, the simplest is to use `root.after`:

```
def refreshSystem():
    do stuff
    root.after(10000, refreshSystem)   # the delay is in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could launch a thread to run a function every n seconds. Would that work for you?

```py
import threading

def do_something():
  print("Hello!")
  threading.Timer(5, do_something).start()

do_something()
```